# Не правильная публикация сайта

Tags: php, css, openserver, localhost

я тот еще чайник в написании сайтов, но тут пришла идея написать сайт, потом решил написать магазин аккаунтов, подумал и решил замутить авторизацию, для этого нужен PHP я написал вроде как рабочий скрипт дляавторизации через VK-API, но вот проблема в том что проверить буз хостинга я PHP не могу, решил как  обычно обойтись open-server и тут он просто записует **HTML в CSS** я немного посмеялся, помучался, и подумал "зачем нужен этот Open Server залью сразу на хост там проверю" на хостингерах тож самое, но когда я запускаю просто index.html без Open Server все работает, и он прекрастно видет файлы со шрифтами, но как не странно PHP не работает, а если заливаю на сервер то CSS не работает. Что делать? Css подключал так (пробывал 4 способа):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css'>    

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/styles.css'>    

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

**UPD-1** Вот тут нашел похожую проблему https://toster.ru/q/202073

Comment: Переименуйте Index.html в Index.php

Comment: и введите в адресной строке  localhost

Comment: В инспекторе перейдите на вкладку Network и нажмите disable cache

Comment: Должно помочь..

Comment: Извините, переименовать было необязательно

Comment: а что выводит localhost/index.php

Comment: Используй тег `<base href="http://адрес твоего сайта/">` в теге `<head></head>`. И тогда просто подключай `css` так: `<link href="css/style.css" rel="..">`. http://htmlbook.ru/html/base. Ну а например подключать `.php файлы` уже надо `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

Comment: Вот это сайтищь.... Надеюсь это пилотный проект, не посудите меня невеждой, но вам следует очень много постичь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Она решается просто, зайдите в инспектор элементов (<kbd>ctrl + shift + i</kbd>) перейдите во вкладку **Network** и нажмите **Disable Cache**

UPD. Все куда проще, просто удалите все строчки из файла .htaccess кроме AddDefaultCharset

Comment: скинте HTML код

Comment: Все куда проще, просто удалите все строчки из файла .htaccess кроме AddDefaultCharset

Comment: Могу сделать пулл реквест

Comment: Уже отредактировал

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста